# IMAP check which mail client the mail came from

Tags: php, imap

I'm trying to create an incoming mail parser using IMAP and I realised different mail clients send mails in different kind of formats (signatures, quotes etc.). So I want to parse the mail differently based on 3 most common mail clients + default for others.

I was wondering how to extract mail client info from received email?

I tried looking at raw headers but I can't seem to figure out the uniform attribute that gets sent. I guess I could look at the host of "from" address (`@gmail.com`, `@outlook.com`), but it wouldn't be right because GSuite mails can have custom hosts, yet still should be parsed like `@gmail.com`.

Anyone has any solutions/ideas?

**EDIT:**

I can't really look at the "from" address at all, because I'm interested in the ***client/app the mail was sent from*** because that's what does the formatting, not the SMTP server.

Answer (score 1):

There is no relationship between the From address or the originating SMTP server and the email client used to send the email. (I have a GMail account but almost all the email I send from it uses the MailMate desktop client and not the GMail web app).

Some emails will include a `X-Mailer` header which will tell you what email client was used. This is optional and many emails will not include it.

You don't have much choice but to apply a heuristic approach and try to match common patterns for expressing quotes to the body of the email.

Comment: Ah you're right, that's a pretty obvious thing I overlooked. I need the client, no matter the SMTP server.